# Get result type of function

Tags: c++, function, boost, type-traits

I want to specialize a template function declared as:

```
template<typename Type> Type read(std::istream& is);
```

I then have a lot of static implementations

```
static int read_integer(std::istream& is);
```

a.s.o. Now I'd like to do a macro so that specialization of read is as simple as:

```
SPECIALIZE_READ(read_integer)
```

So I figured I'd go the boost::function_traits way and declare SPECIALIZE_READ as:

```
#define SPECIALIZE_READ(read_function) \
   template<> boost::function_traits<read_function>::result_type read(std::istream& is) { \
      return read_function(is); \
   }
```

but VC++ (2008) compiler complains with: 'boost::function_traits' : 'read_integer' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'Function'

Ideas ?

Comment: That's because you are passing a value (read_function) as a type. It won't work like that in C++03. In C++0x you can use decltype(read_function).

Comment: Well yes ? What else should I pass ? I've used function_traits successfully with class methods in the past, and I've used it also with functions but I don't know why it doesn't work in this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no mechanism (other than `decltype` in C++0x) to obtain the return type from a function pointer, without passing that same function pointer as a parameter.

The easiest way is to accept the duplication of the return types:

```
#define SPECIALIZE_READ(type, read_function) \
   template<> type read(std::istream& is) { \
      return read_function(is); \
   }

SPECIALIZE_READ(int, read_integer)
```

Comment: Yes, this was my plan B. I'll go with this even though it's not as "neat" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong but if I remember well what I've experienced during my C++ programming carrier, functions may not be overloaded by differing in the return type only. I guess the stuff will work if you do this:

```
template<typename Type> void read(std::istream& is, Type& objectToRead);
```

And use the Type as an argument. This has to do with the way compilers usually decorate c++ names if I recall well.

Comment: Actually, function templates are overloaded based only on the return type quite frequently, for example when using the enable_if idiom on the return type.

Comment: Yes, there is no problem with the overloading, I simple use read<int> read<double> etc. where its needed. The problem seems to be that boost::function_traits doesn't recognize the static function I pass to it...

Comment: Yup, overloads on return type are a problem for non-template functions, because in that case you have no method left to select the right one. With template functions, you can just pick the right instantiation (e.g. `read<int>` - no need for overload resolution)